# VB.NET WebBrowser Control Programmatically Filling Form After Changing User-Agent (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Tags: vb.net, user-agent

I'm working on a project where I have a WebBrowser control which needs to have a custom user-agent set, then go to Google and fill out the search box, click the search button, then click a link from the search results. Unfortunately I can't use HTTPWebRequest, it has to be done with the WebBrowser control.

Before I added the code to change the user-agent, everything worked fine. Here's the code that I have:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

<DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi)> _
Private Shared Function UrlMkSetSessionOption(dwOption As Integer, pBuffer As String, dwBufferLength As Integer, dwReserved As Integer) As Integer
End Function
Const URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT As Integer = &H10000001

Public Sub ChangeUserAgent(Agent As String)
    UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, Agent, Agent.Length, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    ChangeUserAgent("Fake User-Agent")
    wb.Navigate("http://www.google.com", "_self", Nothing, "User-Agent: Fake User-Agent")
End Sub

Private Sub wb_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles wb.DocumentCompleted
    Dim Source As String = wb.Document.Body.OuterHtml
    Dim Uri As String = wb.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri
    If Uri = "http://www.google.com/" Then

        wb.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").SetAttribute("value", "browser info")
        wb.Document.All("btnK").InvokeMember("click")

    End If
    If Uri.Contains("http://www.google.com/search?") Then
        Dim TheDocument = wb.Document.All
        For Each curElement As HtmlElement In TheDocument
            Dim ctrlIdentity = curElement.GetAttribute("innerText").ToString
            If ctrlIdentity = "BROWSER-INFO" Then
                curElement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

The problem lies in the following code:

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib").SetAttribute("value", "browser info")
wb.Document.All("btnK").InvokeMember("click")
```

I thought the problem might be that the page not being fully loaded (frame issue) but I put the offending code in a timer to test, and got the same error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which of these lines creates the error? Is "btnK" the name or id of an element? What kind of element is it?

Comment: @AndyG Both lines create the same error. As I said before, they worked before I added the code to change the user-agent. The first line is to fill the text field with the ID lst-ib with the text 'browser info', the second line is to click the button with the name btnK. Im not sure what you're asking when you say what kind of element is it. The button code is <input value="Google Search" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">.

Comment: You need to be clearer when you write you Q's out, otherwise people will not help you. We cannot imagine what you mean by "both of them create that error", because you cannot ever have two exceptions occurring at the same time. So, you either mean if you swap the lines of code or if you leave one out? I understand what you mean, since you can leave one out in this case, but I had to go to google.com and inspect element on those fields to understand. The least investigative work that we users need to do, the greater the probability that you will get an answer, get me? Welcome to the site, UV'd!

Answer (score 0):

Do you realize `.All("btnK")` returns a collection? So, you are doing `.InvokeMember("click")` on a Collection :). You cannot do that, you can only do `.InvokeMember("click")` on an element for obvious reasons!

Try this:

```
wb.Document.All("btnK").Item(0).InvokeMember("click")
```

The `.Item(0)` returns the first element in the collection returned by `.All("btnK")`, and since there will only probably be one item returned, since there is only one on the page, you want to do the InvokeMember on the first item, being `.Item(0)`.

May I ask what it is you are developing?

Since you're a new user, please up-vote and/or accept if this answered your question.